# Corrupting Navgroups in Titanium Mobile

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

In my app, people go from Window 1 to Window 2 to Window 3 etc, so the navigation goes:
Window 1 -> Window 2 -> Window 3

To go from one window to the next,I use a navigation group:

```
var main = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    height:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,  
    width:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,  
    fullscreen:true, 
    navBarHidden : true,
});

var first = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    height:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,  
    width:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,  
    url:'main_windows/main.js',
    backButtonTitleImage : '../images/backb.gif',
    fullscreen:true, 
    navBarHidden : true,
});

var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
    window:first
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('login', function(event)
{
    var lwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        height:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,  
        width:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,  
        url:'main_windows/login.js',
        barImage: 'images/lback.gif', 
        fullscreen:true, 
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
        navBarHidden : false,
        _parent : Titanium.UI.currentWindow,
        navGroup : navGroup,
        rootWindow : first 
    });

    navGroup.open(lwin);
});

first.navGroup = navGroup;

main.add(navGroup);

main.open();
```

~~~

Then in each window, I open the next window by doing the following:

~~~

```
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Ti.App.fireEvent('services', {
        zipcode : win.zipcode,
        user_id : win.user_id,
        user_uniqid : win.user_uniqid,
        user_name : win.user_name,
        user_email : win.user_email
    });
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('services', function(event) {
    var cwin = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
    var swin = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

    swin.url = 'service.js';

    swin.zipcode = event.zipcode;
    swin.user_id = event.user_id;
    swin.user_uniqid = event.user_uniqid;
    swin.user_name = event.user_name;
    swin.user_email = event.user_email;

    swin.backgroundColor = '#f7f7f7';

    swin._parent = cwin;
    swin.navGroup = cwin.navGroup;
    swin.rootWindow = cwin.rootWindow;
    cwin.navGroup.open(swin);
});
```

~~~

This works well when people go from Window 1 -> Window 2 -> Window 3, but not when they go back:

like from Window 1 -> Window 2 -> Window 3 -> Window 1 -> Window 2

I get the following error when that happens:

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening multiple javascript contexts by using the `url` attribute of `createWindow`, which will kill your system memory pretty fast, especially with more than two heavyweight windows. Put each window into a CommonJS module.

This may not solve your problem, but it is bad practice and its side effects could be the cause.

```
//Dont do this!!

var first = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    ...
    url:'main_windows/main.js', // Bad, opens a new context
    ...
});
```

Instead put it in its own CommonJS module file like so:

```
// main_windows/main.js

function MainWindow() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    // Do all the initialization you were doing to this window in 'main_windows/main.js'
    return self;
}
module.exports = MainWindow;
```

Instantiate it like this:

```
var MainWindow = require('main_windows/main.js');
var first = new MainWindow();
```

This could solve your problem, or at least break your code and resources down to a more manageable state.